# How to print the selected row using asp.net mvc and XtraReports

Tags: xtrareport

I want to be able to print only a specific row from the data-source using xtrareports and MVC4. Can i get any help on that or a link that i can follow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to fill report data source only with necessary data? This way is the most obvious for me to accomplish your task. Please, review these examples, which are similar to your scenario, from DX Support Center:

- [How to filter XtraReport data based on the selected rows in the ASPxGridView](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1613)
- [How to create and print a report for a selected row in the ASPxGridView control](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E1905.aspx)